# RMAN-08138: WARNING: archived log not deleted - must create more backups

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

I have a primary oracle database and a logical standby.

**Primary database information**

```
BANNER                                                                               CON_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production              0
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                                                    0
CORE    12.1.0.2.0  Production                                                            0
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                         0
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                                                    0
```

**Primary rman configuration:**

```
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO SHIPPED TO ALL STANDBY BACKED UP 1 TIMES TO 'SBT_TAPE';
```

**Daily archivelog backups:**

```
backup archivelog until time 'sysdate' keep until time 'sysdate + 30' format '${SID}_D_AL_%U' tag '${SID}_D_AL_${DATE}_${TIME}';
```

**Full backups on weekend:**

```
backup database format '${SID}_DB_%U' tag '${SID}_DB_${DATE_${TIME}' keep until time 'sysdate + 30';
crosscheck backup;
crosscheck archivelog all;
delete noprompt obsolete;
delete expired backup;
```

But ... not alrchivelogs are been deleted.

I tried to manually:

```
delete archivelog all completed before 'sysdate - 10' backed up 1 times to 'SBT_TAPE' ;

RMAN-08138: WARNING: archived log not deleted - must create more backups
archived log file name=+RECO/XXXXXXX/ARCHIVELOG/2021_12_20/thread_2_seq_50845.19381.1091800645 thread=2 sequence=50845

RMAN-08138: WARNING: archived log not deleted - must create more backups
archived log file name=+RECO/XXXXXXX/ARCHIVELOG/2021_12_20/thread_2_seq_50846.19371.1091801255 thread=2 sequence=50846

RMAN-08138: WARNING: archived log not deleted - must create more backups
archived log file name=+RECO/XXXXXXX/ARCHIVELOG/2021_12_20/thread_2_seq_50847.19362.1091802149 thread=2 sequence=50847

RMAN-08138: WARNING: archived log not deleted - must create more backups
archived log file name=+RECO/XXXXXXX/ARCHIVELOG/2021_12_20/thread_2_seq_50848.19359.1091802719 thread=2 sequence=50848
```

If i check v$archivelog:

```
select name, dest_id, registrar, standby_dest,archived,applied,deleted,status
from v$archived_log
where sequence#=50845 and thread#=2;

NAME                                                                        DEST_ID     REGISTR STA ARC APPLIED   DEL S BACKUP_COUNT
------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---------- -------  --- --- --------- --- - ------------
+RECO/XXXXXXX/ARCHIVELOG/2021_12_20/thread_2_seq_50845.19381.1091800645         1       ARCH    NO  YES NO        NO  A     8
XXXXXXstb                                                                       2       LGWR    YES YES YES       NO  A     0
```

If a query rman, i get the 8 backups containing that sequence#, but i dont understed why rman does not delete (automatically by policy) the archivelog and why, when i ask rman to delete archive log, i get ora-08138.

I must be missing something about retention policy...

Comment: RMAN-08138: WARNING: archived log not deleted - must create more backups (Doc ID 2374213.1)

Comment: there is no incremental backup...  but i may be missing something ...the keep until in the archivelog backup prevent the archivelog to be deleted? @sarat what's the point? i have a full backup (1 month retention) and daily archivelog backup.... why does oracle need to keep arvhivelogs? tks